# Why can't routers list clients with static IPs?

Tags: networking, router

Nearly every router I've ever owned does not list devices that have static IPs, regardless if  they are inside or outside the DHCP scope. They only list devices that have been given an address by DHCP. I've seen this on cheap home routers and expensive business routers, and have yet to find one that actually lists all the devices that are connected to it. Why is this?

Comment: When you assign a static IP, the system you do that to doesn't "check in" any where.  There's no opportunity for your router to know about it unless it's sniffing and recording traffic, which most consumer routers don't have the ability to do without third-party firmwares.  You should look into any "reservation" features on your router.  It will tell your router to always give a specific MAC a specific IP - essentially a static IP assigned from the router.  Most routers do support reservations.

Comment: A router would only know a computer is connected to it when packets are being sent. If packets aren't being sent, there's no knowledge of "connection". It would have to issue a broadcast to the broadcast domain, that says "who's listening?" then, compile a list of ip address that respond. But it would be a snapshot, since connectivity to a network is stateless, and networks change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are saying is not completely correct.

On the one hand, components with static IPs are not "clients", i.e., they did not request to the router the use of the DHCP service. They are, in other words, correctly omitted from the DHCP client list.

On the other hand, this does not mean that the router ignores clients using its other services (especially that of routing). These clients must reveal their identity to the router by means of the exchange of ARP traffic (who has 192.168.1.13? tell 192.168.1.1...). These clients are listed in an *ARP table*, which may or may not be accessible to you. For instance, on routers with DD-WRT software (or Open-WRT, or Tomato), the command arp shows the clients that are *active*, i.e., those which are using the router's routing capacity. In fact, in these routers, you will see *two* distinct tables on the GUI, one for DHCP clients, the other one for active clients. The two are, in principle and in fact, different because the latter includes static IPs which are doing something. I think also some Cisco routers show a ARP table (mine surely does).

How about silent clients? Well, those are ignored, and you cannot see them. Why? Because
there is no way for the router to learn of their existence. These include very innocuous components as well as evil ones lurking in the dark. Among the innocuous components, there are things like printers: they do not need to access the Internet thus they ask nothing from the router, and, if they are connected to the other pcs via a switch, their traffic will never even reach the router, it is taken care exclusively by the switch. So, as far as routers are concerned, printers don't even exist.

How about evil ones? They escape detection as long as they keep quiet, for the above-mentioned reasons, but as soon as they start accessing the Internet, you will see them. The problem here is the ARP table has a short TTL (time to live), so that, unless they are downloading via torrent a very large file, your chances of catching them as they access the internet thru your router are pretty slim.

To catch evildoers, a much more suitable instrument is nmap.

Comment: +1 for mentioning ARP. The ARP table is where the router stores a "mapping" of MAC addresses (devices) and the IPs recorded from packets sent by those devices - this doesn't necessarily mean "connected clients", only ones the router is aware of by way of packets sent through it. Many Cisco devices also have CAM tables that are similar to ARP tables, but are for different things.

Comment: This is excellent. I forgot about ARP tables as a viable means of seeing clients. I'll have to remind myself of how usable it is in DD-WRT.

Answer (score 3):

Typically these lists are not described as "connected devices" but as "clients".  And that is exactly what the list shows you, the DHCP clients.  Obviously the machines with static IPs have no interaction with the DHCP server, so they don't show up on the list.

Now, theoretically, the router could enumerate all of the IPs that have sent traffic to it, but there are several reasons why the probably don't.

- First of all that data is deep in the routing/switching software/firmware so its probably not as easily accessible as the log the DHCP server provides.
- DHCP offers have a built in timeout using the DHCP lease time.  The router would have to have some arbitrary timeout to indicate when it thinks a device is no longer active.
- Most people use DHCP, so it works for 95% of the cases.  And in the case of a static IP its assumed that YOU configured it, so you should know that the device is there.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, there's no way to do it.

First, there's no reason for an IP router to know or care what specific devices are connected to your network, and since Ethernet is a fairly passive protocol, there's no need for a host to "check in" with a central server anyway.

The IP address system is designed to work without the need for centralized control over IP addresses. Systems like DHCP and DNS are addons to IP, and they are not necessary for proper IP operation. You can have a perfectly functional network without them.

Add to that the fact that switches are specifically designed to NOT pass traffic that doesn't need to go to a specific host, and this means a router may never see packets from devices like printers, which don't go out to the Internet.

There are things a router could do to identify more hosts on the network, but those all use valuable RAM and CPU resources - something SOHO routers never really have enough of.

If you really want to know who's on your network, you can set up a packet sniffer to log unique MAC's on the network and which IP addresses are associated with those devices. I'm sure there's something out there that can do that, but I can't make any specific recommendations, since I've never had the need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the routers I've had which showed current connections are capable of showing them for all connected hosts regardless of the source of the IP, but many don't even try, because its not valuable to most home-class users.

The router isn't in a position to know about any IP except those it assigns via DHCP, and certainly can't tell if they are static, or just assigned by someone else.

For Instance, I have two DHCP pools for my lan, one for wired and one for wireless, occupying differant ranges. theres no way my gateway router can know what assignments that my wifi AP has made, and since all the addresses coming from the wifi come to my gateway by the same (switched) connection from the wireless APs wired lan connection, theres no way it can tell who is who.

Answer (score 0):

really access points should be able to see any client which is associated, even if it sends no wireless or IP packets.  it may not even have an IP address, but it must have sent some packets in order to associate.

note that "clients" can monitor traffic without associating, but if you are using WPA or WPA2, their ability to decrypt packets is limited.